# Custom Headers get convert into lowercase(using NSURLSession) while sending to server

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, http-headers, nsurlsession

I am using Swift 4, NSUrlSession to make API request.
Within that, I am sending a custom header as below is my code.

**idToken** will contain my value &
**"MyIdToken"** is my Custom Header key

Below is my code:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: fullPath)!)
request?.setValue(idToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "MyIdToken")
```

On the server side, MyIdToken get convert into "myidtoken", which failed to match

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check once in your backend side any where changes all cases to lower

Comment: HTTP headers are defined as case-insensitive. Update your server side code to use case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: Also, file a bug at bugreport.apple.com.  The lack of a case-preserving, case-insensitive dictionary for headers causes a lot of unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Also, if you call `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` instead of `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`, it will not case-canonicalize the header field name, at last check.  (This is likely a bug, and you should not count on it, but that will at least tell you for sure if that's your problem or the problem lies elsewhere.)

Comment: did you find any solution ? I also stuck here